# Internet Explorer clearing browser history mid-session, causing the back and forward buttons to be greyed out

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2, browser-cache, terminal-server

Recently we've had a problem with some of our users; it seems as though IE is clearing it's browser history, forcing the back and forward buttons to not function (both greyed out for the rest of the session). It seems that after you go one layer deep into a website (superuser.com, fine. superuser.com/questions/, nope. (just an example, haven't actually tested this domain.)) it occurs.

This is only a problem with some of our users and there are a handful of websites that seems to work fine. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I should mention that this is only happens on Terminal Servers running Windows Server Edition 2008 R2 64-Bit. Internet explorer v11, this does not happen in v10.

Edit 2: It also clears the users home page.

Side note: I have also posted this problem on Reddit's /r/TechSupport, [here.](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/2ithep/internet_explorer_clearing_browser_history/)

Edit 3: Fixed it. Hint for anyone else with this issue who found this post, force HTTPS and it should work.

Comment: It might look like that was happening if a user clicked on a link that automatically opened in a new tab, and didn't realize that he was in a new tab.

Comment: When I first heard about this problem I actually thought the exact same thing but unfortunately this is not the case. It fully blocks using the back and forward buttons until you completely exit IE, and if you look in the browser history there's nothing there.

Comment: Are there a handful of sites that work fine, or a handful that have the problem? Is there any chance that people are going to sites that are running malicious JavaScript that's messing with their browser settings? (Of course it shouldn't be possible unless your security settings are way too low.)